# when I save the data stored only one data is the other one becomes null. how about using foreach?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

when I save the data stored only one data is the other one becomes null. how about using foreach?

```js
function convertToRupiah(angka){
    var rupiah = '';    
    var angkarev = angka.toString().split('').reverse().join('');
      
    for(var i = 0; i < angkarev.length; i++) 
        if(i%3 == 0) rupiah += angkarev.substr(i,3);
      
    return rupiah.split('',rupiah.length).reverse().join('');
}
  
function showkerugian(str) {
      var temuan = str.replace(/\./g, "",); // update pattern to regex in order to replace all `.` occurrences

      $('#nilai_potensi_kerugian').val(convertToRupiah(temuan));
};
    
$('input#nilai_temuan') .on('keyup focusin focusout ', function(event) {
  if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
  // format number
  $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value.replace(/\D/g, "")
              .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput="showkerugian(this.value)" class="form-control nominal" id="nilai_temuan" >
        <input type="text" class="form-control nominal" name="harga_satuan_pl[]" id="nilai_potensi_kerugian" readonly>
```

the image can be seen below
[image]

can you solve the problem, help me

[image]

Comment: sidenote: better to use classes instead of id since you're expecting multiple text fields to be bound with your custom function

Comment: Please be more specific. Which data is being lost? In which function?

Comment: How? can be explained in more detail @Kevin

Comment: at the time of harga satuan input, can check the picture above@kmoser

Comment: can i ask in bahasa?

Comment: how do I when I input 90,000,000 and 80,000,000 together stored both? the problem now is only the last input @kmoser